# elementui popover does not follow button when scroll

Tags: element-ui

I try to use popover on my page and I create popover when I clicked to button poover opened (but my page does not have scroll, I have inner div scroll) when I try to scroll popover does not follow the button.

How do I fix this. I see some options like `container` I try to apply but I cant, there is any option for that ?

Comment: Could you create an example in codepen https://codepen.io/pen/. As far I tried I don't have any issues with an inner scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try add `slot="reference">` for `el-popover`'s child

EX:

```html
<el-popover
  placement="top-start"
  title="Title"
  width="200"
  trigger="hover"
  content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
  <div slot="reference">
      ...do same think
  </div>
</el-popover>
```